# Javascript always-on-top window (without focus)

Tags: javascript, popup, focus, always-on-top

How can we create a javascript popup window (or something with similar effect) that will remain on top of the primary application window, even when the window below is given focus?

In Linux, this is straightforward within the Window Manager, by using the "always on top" feature, (or of course moving the video window to a 2nd screen) but many of our users have MS Windows 7 and a single screen.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a small, moveable iframe/div/window doing a video conference, which is always visible "above" the main application window, even while users are clicking on and interacting with the main, full-screen, application?

Users can then move that video window around to place it where it's most convenient to them at that moment.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Set the z-index property of your always-on-top component to a higher value than any other element of the page